Apache Superset doesn't logout user on Keycloak logout
I'm experiencing some troubles when user logs out of Keycloak - I also need to log user out of Apache Superset, but it Superset authentication is not deleted. How can I achieve that? Is there any property I can add, like additional logout URL?
